# How do you put html edit text fields in php

Tags: php, html

I want to put two html edittext fields with a label next it saying please input a reg number and a button in the end, whereby the user can input a new registration number. I want to do it within the php script, but I don't know how to incorporate it

Thing is, I am not quite sure how to do this and how to validate the button on click. Like how do I get the values on button click?

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    include "init.php"

    if(!empty($_POST['driverNo'])){
        $driverNoText = $_POST['driverNo'];
        $stmt = "SELECT registrationNo FROM cars WHERE driverNo = ?";
        $result = $conn->prepare( $stmt );
        $result->bind_param( 's', $driverNoText );
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();
        $result->bind_result( $registrationNo );

        while( $result->fetch() )
        {
          echo $registrationNo;
        }

        $result->free_result();
?>
```

Is this even possible or would I have to create a html file and then include this php script?

Sorry, I am quite new to all this web dev stuff

Answer (score 0):

Usually the flow for this kind of single purpose PHP file is that you can include html codes at the end of the PHP script. Treat PHP just like a html file, with a little bit advance thing that it's capable to do more than just HTML.

Which means, the file can be in this kind of format:

```
<?php

//------------------------
// Start of your php inits
// .....................


//------------------------
// Section where you have your code checking
//
if (!empty($_POST...
     //do something useful, sanitize inputs, insert into db
     //echo out something like "thanks for submission here"
} else {
     //you can close the php tag here and put your html codes here
?>
<!doctype html>
.....
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>>
     <input...>
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
//and don't forget the closing bracket
}
```

If you are new and trying out PHP, go ahead and have this as the sample. This is generally not recommended anyway because it's a maintenance nightmare if your code grows. Generally you will need to look for frameworks that can help you with these tedious tasks.